# Raspberry Pi MicroUSB port

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi

Which type of MicroUSB port does RPi use, type A or type B? The Wikipedia page explains nothing, and neither does the Quick Start Guide on the RPi website. (In case you didn't know the difference, check [here](http://www.yogaretnam.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/micro_usb_type_a_b.jpg))

Comment: Make sure to accept @CarlB's answer if it's satisfactory & you're able (it should be, since it's right).  Thanks, and welcome!

Comment: @nerdwaller I've been sick for a few days, sorry C:

Comment: No worries!  Just wanted to remind you - often newb's forget :)  Welcome to SU - hope you're feeling better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Raspberry PI Power_Supply](http://www.petervis.com/Raspberry_PI/Raspberry_PI_Power_Supply/Raspberry_PI_Micro_USB_B_Specification.html) You are looking at a MicroUSB type B port.

The image here would also support that point.

[image: right pic]